# Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $rootScopeProvider <- $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is with template Url in angularjs.

So when i put this code in my editor and run it it works perfectly:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Angular Js</title>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://rawgit.com/nirus/Angular-Route-Injector/master/dist/routeInjector.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.config(function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    template: 'page',

  })

  .when('/helloUser', {
      template: "ds"

  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  })

})
```

[image]

That worked fine but as soon as i try to put a templateUrl It goes of here is my example code for that:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Angular Js</title>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://rawgit.com/nirus/Angular-Route-Injector/master/dist/routeInjector.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

page.html:

```
Hello World
```

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.config(function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'page.html'

  })

  .when('/helloUser', {
      template: "ds"

  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  })

})
```

[image]

EDIT:

1
down vote
accept
You must inject the ngRoute module:

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

Not work:
[image]

Comment: edited scond pic, wil be gone for couple min

Comment: have you tried to include the ngroute module? like var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

Comment: @ewrwr why do you load two different angular versions in your browser + not the official lib for angular router?

Comment: FlorianTopf is right, Maybe you should start with a simple tutorial before you dive in. too many mistakes for a simple task.

Comment: `var app = angular.module('app', ["ui.route.Injector"])` for the lib you are using works (and remove that older angular version (1.0.7)).

Answer (score 1):

You must inject the ngRoute module:

```
<script src="angular-route.js">
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
```

Comment: as members mentioned before, you must remove the reference to the old angularjs library (1.0.7)